# USGS 3DEP DEM, what is an AWS "Staged Product"? Can I access "Staged Product" data over S3?

Tags: geospatial, api, data.gov, usgs

The United States Geological Survey (USGS) has available as part of the 3D Elevation Program (3DEP) a 1-arcsecond Digital Elevation Model (DEM) of the conterminous United States (CONUS) — see [3DEP DEM](https://www.sciencebase.gov/catalog/item/4f70aa71e4b058caae3f8de1).

The data link points to Amazon AWS where data can be downloaded freely and anonymously, but this appears to not be an AWS bucket but rather a [HTTPS index labelled "Staged Products Directory"](https://prd-tnm.s3.amazonaws.com/index.html?prefix=StagedProducts/Elevation/1/ArcGrid/).  When searching the [Registry of Open Data on AWS](https://registry.opendata.aws/) directly, I can only find the related but different [USGS 3DEP LiDAR](https://registry.opendata.aws/usgs-lidar/) product, which is not available freely and anonymously but published as a "requester pays" bucket.

What is an AWS "staged product"?  Are those USGS 3DEP DEM 1-arcminute data available through the AWS S3 interface freely and anonymously, or only through the https interface?  Are those "staged products" https links even permanent?  The https link is very slow; downloading one file, I only got a throughput of 190 KB/s, over three minutes to download a single 35 MiB file.

Answer (score 0):

Staged data is data that is already "prepackaged" as most data requests are clipped from larger datasets and prepared for you to then download via a link.  The staged products are usually in set grids.

Try these:
https://viewer.nationalmap.gov/basic/

https://www.usgs.gov/products/data-and-tools/overview

https://www.usgs.gov/core-science-systems/ngp/3dep

There use to be a bulk downloader but things appear to have changed.